# Minimal eigenvalue of infinite dimensional matrix

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues, closed-form-expressions

Consider the following symmetric, positive-definite matrix
$$
H_{nm}=-\frac{(4 m+4 n+1)}{(4 m-4 n-1) (4 m-4 n+1)}\sqrt{\frac{(4 m-1)!! (4 n-1)!!}{(4 m)!! (4 n)!!}}
$$
where $n,m=0,1,2\dots$ (Here $!!$ is the [semifactorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)).

I am looking for the lowest eigenvalue $\lambda$. (You can define this by truncating $n,m\le N$ and $\lambda=\lim_{N\to\infty}\lambda_N$).

Numerics suggests that $\lambda\approx0.978460482\dots$ Is there a closed-form expression for $\lambda$? Or an effective method to compute it to arbitrary precision? It would be nice, for example, if $H_{nm}$ is a Sturm-Liouville operator in some basis, or something like that.

Note: WolframAlpha's inverse symbolic calculator says that, to the approximation above, $\lambda=\frac{27}{70}+p_c$, where $p_c=0.592746\dots$ is the percolation threshold for a square lattice. This might be just a coincidence. Other symbolic calculators fail to find a candidate for $\lambda$.

Motivation: $\lambda^2\sim 0.95738491\dots$ is the lowest bound on $F[\psi]$ as in this post: [A modified Heisenberg uncertainty relation](https://mathoverflow.net/q/294394/106114), if I am not mistaken. This shows that $1>\lambda^2>0.9$.